# How map JSON data file to SQLIte database using Python

Tags: python, json

I need to convert data from JSON datafile to a SQLite database. The JSON datafile contains the following:

```
{
    "CHILLER_2": {
        "event": {
            "payloadData": {
                "_timestamp": 1573228140000, 
                "CHILLER___TDCOMPB": 0, 
                "CHILLER___TDCOMPA": 82.06, 
                "CHILLER___PEB": 0, 
                "COMPA___E": 83624.896, 
                "CHILLER___TEVDXA": 65.86, 
                "CHILLER___PEA": -4.21, 
                "CHILLER___TEVDXB": 0, 
                "CHILLER___PCA": -4.36, 
                "CHILLER___PCB": 0, 
                "COMPB___P": 0, 
                "CHILLER___TSAC": 88.14, 
                "data_timestamp": "2019-11-08T10:49:00Z", 
                "CHILLER___TEAE": 65.41, 
                "CHILLER___ST": 0, 
                "CHILLER___TSCOMPB": 0, 
                "COMPB___E": 0, 
                "CHILLER___TEAC": 87.24, 
                "COMPA___P": 0.0, 
                "CHILLER___TSCOMPA": 80.15, 
                "CHILLER___TSAE": 60.91
            }
        }
    }, 
    "CHILLER_1": {
        "event": {
            "payloadData": {
                "_timestamp": 1573228140000, 
                "CHILLER___TDCOMPB": 0, 
                "CHILLER___TDCOMPA": 115.25, 
                "CHILLER___PEB": 0, 
                "COMPA___E": 54329.2, 
                "CHILLER___TEVDXA": 55.17, 
                "CHILLER___PEA": -8.54, 
                "CHILLER___TEVDXB": 0, 
                "CHILLER___PCA": 6.74, 
                "CHILLER___PCB": 0, 
                "COMPB___P": 0, 
                "CHILLER___TSAC": 95.9, 
                "data_timestamp": "2019-11-08T10:49:00Z", 
                "CHILLER___TEAE": 45.72, 
                "CHILLER___ST": 2, 
                "CHILLER___TSCOMPB": 0, 
                "COMPB___E": 0, 
                "CHILLER___TEAC": 87.12, 
                "COMPA___P": 198.5, 
                "CHILLER___TSCOMPA": 43.59, 
                "CHILLER___TSAE": 41.67
            }
        }
    }, 
    "BOMBAS": {
        "event": {
            "payloadData": {
                "BAC___P": 27.46, 
                "_timestamp": 1573228140000, 
                "BAF___E": 23893.98, 
                "data_timestamp": "2019-11-08T10:49:00Z", 
                "BAC___E": 23055.22, 
                "BAF___P": 28.48
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So, I need a way to create a table for CHILLER_1, CHILLER_2 and BOMBAS datasets with the corresponding data.

Personally, I'm newbie with Python, so any help will be apreciated.

Any suggestion on how do I achieve that?

Comment: Please rephrase as a question and not as an outsourcing task.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `pd.DataFrame` passing the correct path of the json:

```
import pandas as pd
chiller_2 = pd.DataFrame(data['CHILLER_2']['event']['payloadData'],index=[0])
chiller_1 = pd.DataFrame(data['CHILLER_1']['event']['payloadData'],index=[0])
bombas = pd.DataFrame(data['BOMBAS']['event']['payloadData'],index=[0])
print(chiller_2)
print(chiller_1)
print(bombas)
```

Output:

```
[1 rows x 21 columns]

C:\Users\Ivan L\Desktop\Python>soo.py
      _timestamp  CHILLER___TDCOMPB  CHILLER___TDCOMPA  CHILLER___PEB       ...        CHILLER___TEAC  COMPA___P  CHILLER___TSCOMPA  CHILLER___TSAE
0  1573228140000                  0              82.06              0       ...                 87.24        0.0              80.15           60.91

[1 rows x 21 columns]
      _timestamp  CHILLER___TDCOMPB  CHILLER___TDCOMPA  CHILLER___PEB       ...        CHILLER___TEAC  COMPA___P  CHILLER___TSCOMPA  CHILLER___TSAE
0  1573228140000                  0             115.25              0       ...                 87.12      198.5              43.59           41.67

[1 rows x 21 columns]
   BAC___P     _timestamp   BAF___E        data_timestamp   BAC___E  BAF___P
0    27.46  1573228140000  23893.98  2019-11-08T10:49:00Z  23055.22    28.48
```

Once you have them in a RDB structure, you can insert it into a table, or create table in your sql.

Comment: What is pd.DataFrame? It's an external library?

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry it's from pandas I've edited my answer to include it. Pandas is the library, DataFrame() is a function.

Comment: After running the script, I got the following error: 

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/Erick Coronell/Python workspace/gas-prices/test.py", line 2, in <module>
    chiller_2 = pd.DataFrame(data['CHILLER_2']['event']['payloadData'],index=[0])
NameError: name 'data' is not defined`

Comment: You should name your json data file to `data` which is the name I'm giving it since you didn't define it.